# using IN in IN query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I cant combine this query, but if execute separately both work fine.

```
select name 
   from zone 
   where id IN (select proj_tbl_id from project where proj_name = '$project2')
```

The result of the 2nd query

```
select proj_tbl_id from project where proj_name = '$project2') = (13,14)
```

If run like below, the result is true.

```
select name from zone where id IN (13,14)
```

Comment: what if you get the `proj_tbl_id` first and then make a second query using the value returned by first query?

Comment: @AD8 That would undesirable from a latency point of view.

Comment: Please make this question reproducible.  You are saying that the error should not be happening, when in fact it is.

Comment: maybe the value of `$project2` contains a `'` (or some other chars breaking the query) and breaks the query? You should use prepared statements!

Comment: it works fine even i put the exact value, it runs if separately..

Comment: Post your php code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `exists` operator:

```
SELECT name
FROM   zone z
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   project p
               WHERE  z.id = p.proj_tbl_id AND
                      proj_name = '$project2')
```

Comment: cant join using id coz the value for proj_tbl_id is 13,14 while id has 13 and 14 different row.